# "Release" powershell immediately after launching a script

Tags: windows, powershell

I'd like to be able to "unlink" PowerShell after succesfully launching a script I've made instead of anchoring the instance to the script's lifecycle.

Is there something I can put into the script to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  What issue are you having that you think this will solve?

Comment: @boxdog I've made a simple ps script that keeps Windows alive but I'd like to run it without a powershell windows always open and linked to its lifecycle

Comment: Are you asking how to run PowerShell in the background, without a window? Something like `powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -File C:\script.ps1`